# What should be the excel VLOOKUP formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

If in the table array used in VLOOKUP formula, there are two columns: ID and Paid

The data given in the table array are as follows:

| ID | Paid |
| --- | --- |
| A | NaN |
| A | NaN |
| B | YES |
| C | NaN |
| B | NaN |
| C | NaN |
| A | YES |

What should be the EXCEL formula to get

A -> YES

B -> YES

C -> NaN

LOGIC: For any ID if the PAID column is has at least one YES the VLOOKUP result should be YES, if the ID does not have at least one YES the VLOOKUP result should be NaN for that ID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IF` and `COUNTIFS`:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(A:A,D2,B:B,"YES"),"YES","NaN")
```

[image]

Comment: Or, may be this one, `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(1,(D2=$A$2:$A$8)*($B$2:$B$8="YES"),0)),"YES","NaN")`